# Change position of y axis label to bottom of windows forms chart

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, alignment

Actually my chart is looking like that:

[image]

As you can see the labels are overlapped with the other series. How can I set the label for series2 (=columns) to the bottom above the x-axis? It seems there is no property for that?
Thanks

Comment: im not really sure what you want to do -maybe this helps 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351054/winform-ui-components-layer-order

Comment: No, you can't freely place the datapoint labels nor align them to the top of the chart. You could try to add the Xaxis2 and try to show the values of one series there..

Comment: @while : he is talking about the labels in a MsChart, not Label controls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the y-values of one series at one axis. This can be the primary axis (at the bottom), but then the x-values won't show. Or it can be the secondary axis; for this here is what you can do:

First enable the second x-axis :

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

Then associate the series you want to this secondary axis:

```
yourSeries.XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```

Finally tell the series to display its y-values on its axis labels:

```
yourSeries.AxisLabel = "#VAL";
```

If your other series shows its values close to the points:

```
yourOtherSeries.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

..this could be the result :

[image]

Here I have colored the axis labels to go with their series:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.LabelStyle.ForeColor = yourSeries.Color;
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect! Little error: `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2 = AxisEnabled.True;` is `.Enabled` missing -> `chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;`.