# Show Groupbox when button is clicked or Bring GroupBox to front?

Tags: c#

I have 3 GroupBox's that contain various TextBox's and Buttons, I have placed the 3 GroupBox's on top of each other and created 4 buttons so that when one of the buttons is clicked the GroupBox it refers to is shown above the other. To do this I tried .Visible and .BringToFront command. But It didn't work.

```
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LOGINGROUP.Visible = true;
    LOGINGROUP1.Visible = false;
    LOGINGROUP2.Visible = false;
}

private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LOGINGROUP1.Visible = true;
    LOGINGROUP.Visible=false;
    LOGINGROUP2.Visible = false;
}

private void bunifuFlatButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LOGINGROUP2.Visible = true;
    LOGINGROUP1.Visible = false;
    LOGINGROUP.Visible = false;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WinForm UI components layer order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351054/winform-ui-components-layer-order)

Comment: Can you check if you accidentally put the group boxes in one another ?

Comment: You talk about 4 groupboxes but you hide/show only three. Were is the fourth? Also check if you have nested them.

Comment: I checked it's not and sorry there is just 3 group boxes at the same location.

Comment: Have you tried using `.BringToFront`?

Comment: Yes I tried but for some reasons it's not working

Comment: Use View > Other Windows > Document Layout to see that these groupboxes don't actually overlap.  You can fix it by dragging the nested box up so they all have the same parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason why you can't use the TabControl Control?

From my understanding of your description, the button is also placed inside the groupbox. if they are all on top of each other, then you can only click on the button of the top groupbox.

**If the above is not the case**

This problem is most likely caused by the behaviour of groupboxes in Visual Studio's designer. When a groupbox is placed on top of another in the designer, the top box is automatically placed **inside** the bottom box, this can be seen in the following code produced by the designer:

```
        // 
        // groupBox1
        // 
        this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
        this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
        this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
        this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(232, 227);
        this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";
```

The highlight is this part:

```
this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.groupBox2);
```

as you can see, groupBox2 is placed as a control of groupBox1, this causes problems in sending to front since the only control in group is itself and the textboxes that are being overlapped by it.

to fix this, you can simply change

```
this.groupBoxX.Controls.Add(this.groupBoxY);
```

to

```
this.Controls.Add(this.groupBoxY);
```

or otherwise, simply declare the groupboxes yourself instead of relying on the designer. (however, this requires declaring the textboxes and handlers manually as well)

Comment: No there is buttons inside the group boxes and also there is a menu with buttons. When I click to a button from menu I want to change the group box